# How do I correctly set up a custom 'through' table in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I am trying to set up a custom through table in a project which uses Sequelize. I have a Plannings table and a Tasks table. Now, I wish to implement a table which relates the two, but I want to add a custom column 'done'. When running `sync()`, it seems that all tables are set up properly. This is the query it runs to set up the PlanningTask table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PlanningTask` 
(`done` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, `PlanningId` INTEGER(11) , `TaskId` INTEGER(11) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`PlanningId`, `TaskId`), 
FOREIGN KEY (`PlanningId`) REFERENCES `Plannings` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (`TaskId`) REFERENCES `Tasks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) 
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here are the current models:
task.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
    })
    Task.associate = function(models) {
        Task.belongsToMany(models.Planning, {
            through: 'PlanningTask'
        })
    }
    // Methods
    return Task
}
```

planning.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Planning = sequelize.define('Planning', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
    })
    Planning.associate = function (models) {
        Planning.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey: 'owner'
        })
        Planning.belongsToMany(models.Task, {
            through: 'PlanningTask'
        })
  }
  // Methods
  return Planning
}
```

planningtask.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const PlanningTask = sequelize.define('PlanningTask', {
    done: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true       
    })
    PlanningTask.associate = function (models) {
        PlanningTask.belongsTo(models.Planning)
        PlanningTask.belongsTo(models.Task)
  }
  // Methods
  return PlanningTask
}
```

All models are loaded with the following index.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
    file !== 'index.js'
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
    db[model.name] = model
  })

Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db)
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

I wondered whether there might be some issue with the order (the associations are registered in the order Planning, PlanningTask, Task) but when I change the order it still does not work. The table is created correctly, but when I try to input a Task using planning.add([task]), it runs the following query:

```
SELECT `done`, `PlanningId`, `TaskId`
FROM `PlanningTask` AS `PlanningTask`
WHERE `PlanningTask`.`PlanningId` = 1 AND `PlanningTask`.`TaskId` IN (1);
```

So, for PlanningId it tries to '= 1' which is correct, but then for TaskId it uses 'IN (1)', which is not correct. 1 in this case is the correct Task Id.

Is there something I am doing wrong in the associations, or is there a problem in the way I am trying to input Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The 'done' column was still set to required and in my tests I wasn't sending a value for it, the rest worked fine.